# How to correctly route from page to another in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to route to an edit page using the link

```
 <Link
    to={`/update/${ad._id}`}
    className="btn btn-xs btn-round btn-o btn-green dropdown-toggle"
    >
   <span className="fa fa-pencil"></span>
Edit
 </Link>
```

in the target component am loading some javascript files at `componendDidMount` using customized function
like below

```
this.loadScript('js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
```

source

```
loadScript(src) {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = false;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

yet when the page loads I can find many errors in the console similar to

```
GET http://localhost:3000/update/js/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I guess the it should have been loading `http://localhost:3000/js/bootstrap.js` instead
noting that files loads for paths similar this pattern `/somepage` but not `/somepage/:id`

and this is the router am using

what could be the issue ?

Comment: may if you read about "exact path" or not "exact path" in react router librarie you may find what the cause of your problem related to path and wildcards in slug form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
this.loadScript('js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
```

to:

```
this.loadScript('/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'); // note the beginning slash
```

in routing concept, when the route not starting with a slash is considered a "relative path", but if it has a starting slash it will be used as an "absolute path".